# her + direct object + self

Tags: meaning-in-context

Explain, pls, in other words what she does, what is written in bold, and what exactly the word "self" here below means:
"Story about Rock Star"
Rock Star Amy Lee brings **her goth girl self** to the table and to the recording studio, no questions asked.

Comment: Please cite the source of this. You can [edit] your question to add the link.

Comment: Dear friend, it's from some English book with short stories to read and develop vocabulary, unfortunately it contains no links

Comment: Name of the book? It seems to have been taken from http://faze.ca/amy-lee-of-evanescence-her-life-the-group/, but perhaps edited somewhat. Please  [edit] your question to name the "English Book".

Answer (score 2):

The question needs to be asked in the context of the idiom:

idiomatic expression: **to bring something [here: her goth girl self] to the table**

meaning: to have something to offer people in some situation.

A goth girl is a girl who dresses in the goth style.

goth girl self goes  one step beyond that and suggests that a goth girl (or guy for that matter) not only dress in goth style but they have a personality [self] to match the attire.

It says her in the same way you would say her personality. It means it belongs to her and not to a general class of people.